# Back-off restarting failed container while creating a redis deployment in k8s

Tags: redis, kubernetes

I am trying to launch a deployment object in k8s with kubernetes/redis image. But I am getting   error **Back-off restarting failed container**. The issue occurs with just **redis** image and I am able to successfully run deployments with postgres image etc.

Here is the config file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: redis
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: kubernetes/redis
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

Describe pod output:

```
Name:               redis-deployment-57dcf8ff69-9v8sz
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:         Sun, 10 Mar 2019 11:13:00 +0530
Labels:             component=redis
                    pod-template-hash=57dcf8ff69
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 172.17.0.8
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/redis-deployment-57dcf8ff69
Containers:
  redis:
    Container ID:   docker://556544175a99da6cd704ddc5ae6e65ee0a424275872d86543bbfef6eebceff5b
    Image:          kubernetes/redis
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://kubernetes/redis@sha256:60e8254f473b1df64340da257e8e0a029c0ac67a76bdde296f11eba6cde515c7
    Port:           6379/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 10 Mar 2019 20:12:26 +0530
      Finished:     Sun, 10 Mar 2019 20:13:28 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  13
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zqj5b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-zqj5b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-zqj5b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From               Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       9h                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/redis-deployment-57dcf8ff69-9v8sz to minikube
  Normal   Pulling         5h (x5 over 9h)    kubelet, minikube  pulling image "kubernetes/redis"
  Normal   Pulled          5h (x5 over 5h)    kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "kubernetes/redis"
  Normal   Created         5h (x5 over 5h)    kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started         5h (x5 over 5h)    kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Warning  BackOff         5h (x53 over 5h)   kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   SandboxChanged  17m                kubelet, minikube  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling         11m (x4 over 16m)  kubelet, minikube  pulling image "kubernetes/redis"
  Normal   Pulled          11m (x4 over 16m)  kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "kubernetes/redis"
  Normal   Created         11m (x4 over 16m)  kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started         11m (x4 over 16m)  kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Warning  BackOff         1m (x39 over 15m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

I am using the **kubernetes/redis** image in this example as using **redis** image completely fails because kubectl is not able to get the image pulled from dockerhub and I get the error which says failed in pulling the image. Not sure why !

Can anyone please help me out here.

EDIT---

Logs

```
kubectl.exe logs redis-deployment-57dcf8ff69-9v8sz
Could not connect to Redis at -p:6379: Name or service not known
Failed to find master.
```

Comment: Can you send logs?

Comment: @Arslanbekov  added to the post under edit.

Comment: I am not sure which image you are using. It looks like kubernetes moved their images to gcr, so I guess that you are using old image from docker hub? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/6a60f8e542ea7bb14c280bb02bdc209d42d8b222

Comment: @Amityo. Thanks. Will try to use the image from GCR and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Below config file worked for me.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: redis
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/redis:v1
          env:
            - name: MASTER
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```